# How to randomly select n items from permutation list in Python

Tags: python, list, function, random, permutation

I want to select some random set of grouped items from permutation list. How to do it in a single function call or maybe with minimal code.
For Eg:

```
A=[1,2,3]
```

If I input list A and a requirement (say 2) means, from all possible permutations

```
[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [3,1,2], [3,2,1],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]
```

I have to get randomly two list.
Should return :
 [3,1,2],[2,1,3] or any other random two lists/tuple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random picks from permutation generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602488/random-picks-from-permutation-generator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use numpy random permutation.

```
random_arr_func = lambda x:[list(np.random.permutation(your_list)) for i in range(2)]
list(b(your_list))
```