# Iterate though all permutations randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have imported an large array and I want to iterate through all row permutations at random.
The code is designed to break if a certain array produces the desired solution.
The attempt so far involves your normal iterative perturbation procedure:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

file = np.loadtxt("my_array.csv", delimiter=", ")
for i in itertools.permutations(file):
    ** do something **
    if condition:
        break
```

However, I would like the iterations to cover all perturbation and at random, with no repeats.

Ideally, (unlike [random iteration in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252373/random-iteration-in-python)) I would also avoid storing all permutations of the array in memory.
Therefore a generator based solution would be best.
Is there a simple solution?

Comment: is it a requirement that it remains a generator? Otherwise it would be pretty simple to convert the result to a list and then shuffle that

Comment: @questionerofdy, I should say that the ideal result would not store a large number of permutations in memory. I shall add this comment to my question - but good thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to first write a function that given an integer k in [0, n!) returns the kth permutation:

```
def unrank(n, k):
    pi = np.arange(n)
    while n > 0:
        pi[n-1], pi[k % n] = pi[k % n], pi[n-1]
        k //= n
        n -= 1
    return pi
```

This technique is found in [Ranking and unranking permutations in linear time](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.216.9916&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Wendy Myrvold and Frank Ruskey.

Then, if we can generate a random permutation of [0, n!) we are done. We can find a technique for this (without having to construct the whole permutation) in [Sometimes-Recurse Shuffle](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/560.pdf) by Ben Morris and Phillip Rogaway. I have an implementation of it available [here](https://gist.github.com/orlp/33535eefce782a59e185e4a971cda1a3).

Then, all we have to do is:

```
import math
a = np.array(...)  # Load data.
p = SometimeShuffle(math.factorial(len(a)), "some_random_seed")
for kth_perm in p:
    shuffled_indices = unrank(len(a), kth_perm)
    shuffled_a = a[shuffled_indices]
```

Comment: The `random_perms()` seems not really generating random permutations. The iterated permutations are highly ordered.

Comment: @LibinWen Yeah you're right, I deleted that part of the answer. The first picked permutation is random but then it's correlated with the next one, etc.